# PostgreSQL: Getting STRING_AGG to respect the ordering from a CTE

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-agg

I'm creating a report, showing staff members' former teams along with the date they left, aggregated into a single field in the report. This works to a degree:

```sql
WITH "most_recent_leave_dates" AS (
    SELECT
        staff_id, -- alphanumeric string
        team,
        MAX(date_left) AS "most_recent_date_left"
    FROM team_membership
    WHERE date_left IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY staff_id, team
    -- I thought ordering this CTE would do it, but no
    ORDER BY staff_id, most_recent_date_left DESC
)
SELECT
    staff_id,
    STRING_AGG(
        DISTINCT CONCAT(team, ' until ' || most_recent_date_left),
        CHR(10) -- separate by newline
    ) AS "teams"
FROM most_recent_leave_dates
GROUP BY staff_id
```

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jZCcKRWNV8vLJUFsa6kq7/2

But `STRING_AGG` is sorting the terms alphabetically. I want them sorted by `most_recent_date_left`. How can I do that?

The [documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/functions-aggregate.html) states:

> Alternatively, supplying the input values from a sorted subquery will
> usually work.

Do I have to rewrite the CTE as a subquery…?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ORDER BY` is meaningless in the CTE.  You can `ORDER BY` as part of the `STRING_AGG()`:

```
SELECT staff_id,
       STRING_AGG(CONCAT(team, ' until ' || most_recent_date_left),
                  CHR(10)
                  ORDER BY most_recent_date_left DESC
                 ) AS "teams"
FROM most_recent_leave_dates
GROUP BY staff_id;
```

Comment: I swear I tried that and it insisted I `ORDER BY` the entire `CONCAT` statement. Thanks, this is better.

Comment: @JackDeeth . . . The `ORDER BY` wouldn't work with the `DISTINCT`, so it probably generated an error.  Cheers.

Comment: Maybe the question title should be "how do I write SQL and stay sane when my only debugging feedback is a tiny popup window emanating from the bowels of SAP BusinessObjects"… might have to build an offline mockup with representative dummy data.

Comment: "The `ORDER BY` is meaningless in the CTE" only if the CTE's ordering is overwritten by another `ORDER BY` in `STRING_AGG`, right? Without `DISTINCT` in the `STRING_AGG` I can order the results just fine by ordering the CTE only: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jZCcKRWNV8vLJUFsa6kq7/3

Comment: @JackDeeth . . . That it *sometimes* works is not a guarantee.  I would suggest you carefully read the accepted answer on this question:  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/130552/in-postgresql-is-the-row-ordering-preserved-in-functions-and-ctes.

Answer (score 1):

Just remove distinct from outer query as below (I don't think you need this). Your data is already sorted in cte by staffid and most_recent_date_left.

**Schema (PostgreSQL v9.6)**

```
CREATE TABLE "team_membership" (
  staff_id text,
  team text,
  date_left date
);


INSERT INTO team_membership VALUES
('aaaa', 'B team', '2019-01-01'),
('aaaa', 'A team', '2021-01-01'),
('aaaa', 'C team', '2020-01-01'),
('aaaa', 'A team', '2018-01-01');
```

---

**Query #1**

```
WITH "most_recent_leave_dates" AS (
    SELECT
        staff_id, 
        team,
        MAX(date_left) AS "most_recent_date_left"
    FROM team_membership
    WHERE date_left IS NOT NULL
    GROUP BY staff_id, team              
)
SELECT
    staff_id,
    STRING_AGG(
         CONCAT(team, ' until ' || most_recent_date_left),
        CHR(10) order by most_recent_date_left  desc
    ) AS "teams"
FROM most_recent_leave_dates
GROUP BY staff_id;
```

| staff_id | teams |
| --- | --- |
| aaaa | A team until 2021-01-01 C team until 2020-01-01 B team until 2019-01-01 |

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/jZCcKRWNV8vLJUFsa6kq7/2)

Comment: As per the other answer, ordering of a CTE is not guaranteed… so `ORDER BY` belongs in the `STRING_AGG`.

Comment: Appreciate your concern. I have also changed my answer. Best wishes.